# Flex : How to disable a leaf in a <mx:Tree> at runtime

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I have to parse a string as XML. The parsed XML has to be displayed in Tree control box. The leaves in the tree should be disabled according to an attribute particular to the element.

Sample string that i receive from backend.

```
public var myDataStr: String = 
                <node label="Root" checked="0">    
                    <node label="Datacenter" moref="datacenter-21" type="Datacenter" checked="0">        

                        <node label="10.255.0.30" moref="host-6371" type="HostSystem" checked="disabled" ipAddress="10.255.0.30"/>   
                    </node>    
                    <node label="Datacenter1" moref="datacenter-6349" type="Datacenter" checked="0">      
                        <node label="10.255.0.29" moref="host-6043" type="HostSystem" checked="disabled" ipAddress="10.255.0.29"/>   
                        <node label="10.255.0.25" moref="host-28" type="HostSystem" checked="0" ipAddress="10.255.0.25"/>    
                    </node>
                </node>
```

The following code displays the data.

```
public function displayData(event:MouseEvent):void
            {       
                    myData = new XML(myDataStr)
                    myDropdown.dataProvider = new XMLListCollection(myData.children());
                    myDropdown.selectedIndex = 0;       
                    hostXMLlistColl = new XMLListCollection(myData.node[datacenter_Dropdown.selectedIndex].children());
                    myTree.dataProvider = hostXMLlistColl
            }
```

The nodes that have checked="disabled" have to be grayed out.

Please suggest how to do this.

Comment: This might help you to get started: http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2007/06/disabling_list_selection.html . This is for a List but Tree will work in a similar way. Or do you want just to change the color to grey but keep the items selectable ? This can be done with a simple custom item renderer